# Enviar deep link desde Google cloud messaging

Tags: android

Estoy usando el servicio de Google cloud messaging para enviar push notification a mi app en android.

Ahora me interesaría enviar un deep link en los push notifications, para que cuando el usuario presione sobre el push, le lleve directamente a una sección dentro de la app

¿Será posible hacer esto, o definitivamente tendré que usar servicios de pago donde si ofrecen el deep link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que se puede lograr, obviamente tendrías que agregar otro dato en la notificación, por ejemplo "deepUrl" que podría contener el nombre de la sección, un url :

```
http://www.marcos.com/nacional
```

o un custom scheme:

```
seccion://nacional
```

en base a eso, cuando recibas tu notificación en `onHandleIntent()`, abrir tu sección.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);        
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (!extras.isEmpty()){  
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)){

                                             String titulo = extras.getString("titulo");
                                             String descripcion = extras.getString("descripcion");
                                             String imagen = extras.getString("img");
                                             String deepUrl = extras.getString("deepUrl");

                                             abreSeccion(deepUrl);



        }else{
            Log.w(TAG, "Tipo de notificación desconocido.");
        }
    }        
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```